# What is the meaning of "span" in unix

Tags: unix, html

I'm new here, and new to unix. Sry if I sound dumb.
What does "The \ also allows you to span command across a line." mean?
Its from my lecture notes but I don't understand.
What is span command?

Comment: You would be better asking this on [unix.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When entering a command in Unix you can break the command across multiple lines by entering a backslash `\` at the end of each line

E.g.

```
cp file1 file2 <return>
```

could be

```
cp file1 \
file2 <return>
```

For a short command like this it makes little sense, but it would make a long command easier to read as you type it.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have to put the entire command on one line. Span allows the command to continue over multiple lines.

i.e.

```
ls \
-l
```

is equivalent to:

```
ls -l
```